# append a json and read it back

Tags: python, json

On event, I append the event to a event txt file (important that I append to text file and not keep it in memory) after accumulation of 10 events I need to POST that to event server
My sample event is :

```
data = {
            'node': os.popen('hostname').read(),
            'details': details,
            'time': calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())

    }
```

Iam able to append hence comes out as

```
{
    "node": "macbook.local\n", 
    "details": "Fire", 
    "time": 1443734264
}{
    "node": "macbook.local\n", 
    "details": "Fire", 
    "time": 1443734272
}
```

Iam unable to read it back
tried :

```
with open(tmp_file) as source:
        json_source = source.read()
        data = json.loads('[{}]'.format(json_source))
```

but throws exception.

May be i need to treat it like a list, is that the only way?

-- python newbie

Comment: can you post the exception you see?

Answer (score 0):

First, when you append the data, make sure you add a comma to the end of it:

```
{
    "node": "macbook.local\n", 
    "details": "Fire", 
    "time": 1443734264
},{
    "node": "macbook.local\n", 
    "details": "Fire", 
    "time": 1443734272
},
```

Second, when you reformat it, only use list brackets (`[]`), not dictionary brackets (`{}`), like so:

```
    data = json.loads('[]'.format(json_source))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you don't have your json formatted as a proper API. Try this:

```
a='{"someid":{"node": "macbook.local","details": "Fire", "time": "1443734264"},"someid2":{"node": "macbook.local", "details": "Fire", "time": "1443734272"}}'
json.loads(a)
{'someid': {'details': 'Fire', 'node': 'macbook.local', 'time': '1443734264'}, 'someid2': {'details': 'Fire', 'node': 'macbook.local', 'time': '1443734272'}}
```

Comment: I cant use someid, because the script is called randomly

Comment: I don't think any well-written json api should be giving out data like that, it is filled with style errors. If you can't change it, then I would probably use regex to style it properly myself by matching brackets.